# Business Website Fraudulently Copied; What Can We Do to Get Fraudulent Chinese Site Taken Down

Tags: copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alot of Pirated Material on Someone's Website - What Can Be Done?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/alot-of-pirated-material-on-someones-website-what-can-be-done)

My company, http://www.dakim.com, has had its content mirrored by another site, www.ebrainease.com. They have done a search-and-replace for our company's name, but left our management team in place, so it looks like we're directly connected with their company. They're also using stock photos which we've licensed, and altered documents so it looks like the clinical trial we performed was done by them. Obviously, this is of great concern to my company.

Whois reports that ebrainease.com is registered by a Liang Hongcai in China. We've emailed this person to request that they take down our content, with no response to date.

Judging from ICANN's FAQ, contacting them won't be fruitful: https://www.icann.org/en/dispute-resolution/#content

We are having trouble finding an address to email at the registrar, xinnet.com.

We will also be contacting the host, CNC Group CHINA169 Henan Province Network.

Due to the difference in laws between the United States and China, I'm not hopeful that we will have much luck with the host or registrar. (Perhaps I'm too cynical.)

Are there any other avenues we can pursue?

Answer (score 2):

As someone who lives in China and sees this all the time, the only thing that will get you results (unless you have a Chinese official on your payroll) is to hammer all the major search engines with your complaint and try to get that site de-listed from their indexes.

They will still exist within the PRC, of course, but they will be internationally invisible.

**This** is actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I think you'll not shut down the website just mailing the provider or the owner. The latter has stolen your content, so he's not honest and so he will never close his (cloned) website. The only think you have to do is going to a lawyer and sues him.